# Webpack keeps on creating dist folder?

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

I'm working on server side coding using Node.js. I've noticed Webpack (I think) is randomly creating `dist` folder with `.dev.js` files. I'm not running build, I'm starting server with nodemon `npm run start`.

**Image of what I'm talking about**
[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "card-match-game-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash.shuffle": "^4.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.6",
    "socket.io": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Can someone clarify why those `dist` folders are auto generated and the purpose of it? Thanks.